# pyspark: create more than 1 dataframe fails

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'd like to convert several large Pandas dataframes into Spark dataframes and then manipulate and merge them, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext,SQLContext

df1 = pd.read_csv('data1.cat',delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('data2.cat',delim_whitespace=True)

sc = SparkContext()
sql = SQLContext(sc)
spark_df1 = sql.createDataFrame(df1)
spark_df2 = sql.createDataFrame(df2)
```

But something goes wrong, and I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/conda_py3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 307, in createDataFrame
    return self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/conda_py3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 724, in createDataFrame
    data = self._convert_from_pandas(data, schema, timezone)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/conda_py3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 487, in _convert_from_pandas
    np_records = pdf.to_records(index=False)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/conda_py3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1839, in to_records
    return np.rec.fromarrays(arrays, dtype={"names": names, "formats": formats})
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/records.py", line 617, in fromarrays
    descr = sb.dtype(dtype)
ValueError: name already used as a name or title
```

Is it possible to create multiple Spark dataframes in the same session like this?

Comment: yes, you can create multiple Spark dataframes in the same session. I think issue is with your data, possibly having the same column names in the input files. Please verify!

Comment: Yes, both dataframes have one column in common. My intention was to use this common column to join the two dataframes.

Comment: try df2.columns to see if any column is repeated in df2.  Then try df1.columns to see if any column is repeated in df1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is thrown because your pandas DataFrame (`df1` of `df2`) has the same column name for 2 or more columns. Either change the columns name or drop it.

Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: Hi Sagar and Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you take a look here on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), this way you can ensure the most people can take benefit from it!